# programming trouble action listener?

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to make a game called ratsuk. Its like chess but only with the knight. I have problem with the movement of the knight atm. Some times when i press a button other knight appears were it shouldn't(well were i don't want to) Im pretty sure its a problem with the action listener that some how its running method caballo more than once at a time. But i just cant figure it out. I am quite desperate please help me. I'm really new to java.

Here is the part that i need help with.

```
public void caballo(final int row, final int column) {

    final JButton current = mesa[row][column];

    current.setIcon(image);
    panel.repaint();

    acciones(row, column, current);
}

public void acciones(final int row, final int column, final JButton current) {

    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            mesa[i][j].addActionListener(e(row, column, current));
        }
    }
}

public ActionListener e(final int row, final int column,
        final JButton current) {
    return new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (tienebotton(row + 2, column + 1)) {
                if (e.getSource() == mesa[row + 2][column + 1]) {

                    current.setIcon(null);
                    caballo(row + 2, column + 1);
                    ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
            if (tienebotton(row + 2, column - 1)) {
                if (e.getSource() == mesa[row + 2][column - 1]) {

                    current.setIcon(null);
                    caballo(row + 2, column - 1);

                    ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
            if (tienebotton(row - 2, column - 1)) {
                if (e.getSource() == mesa[row - 2][column - 1]) {

                    current.setIcon(null);
                    caballo(row - 2, column - 1);

                    ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
            if (tienebotton(row - 2, column + 1)) {
                if (e.getSource() == mesa[row - 2][column + 1]) {

                    current.setIcon(null);
                    caballo(row - 2, column + 1);

                    ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);

                }
            }

            if (tienebotton(row + 1, column + 2)) {
                if (e.getSource() == mesa[row + 1][column + 2]) {

                    current.setIcon(null);
                    caballo(row + 1, column + 2);

                    ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
            if (tienebotton(row - 1, column + 2)) {
                if (e.getSource() == mesa[row - 1][column + 2]) {

                    current.setIcon(null);
                    caballo(row - 1, column + 2);

                    ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
            if (tienebotton(row + 1, column - 2)) {
                if (e.getSource() == mesa[row + 1][column - 2]) {

                    current.setIcon(null);
                    caballo(row + 1, column - 2);

                    ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
            if (tienebotton(row - 1, column - 2)) {
                if (e.getSource() == mesa[row - 1][column - 2]) {

                    current.setIcon(null);
                    caballo(row - 1, column - 2);

                    ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);

                }
            }
        }

    };
}
```

any kind of advice is welcome.

this is tienebotton i put so it didnt gave me Array Index Out of Bounds Exception :

```
public boolean tienebotton(int row, int column) {
        return (row >= 0 && row < HEIGHT && column >= 0 && column < WIDTH);

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest that you use a debugger or `System.out.println()` calls to verify that `caballo()` is called too many times. Learning to debug your code is a critical skill for every programmer.

Comment: What does `tienebotton` do? I guess that logic can be simplified.

Comment: Seems like in `acciones` you are attaching an action listener to each button every time you make a move, wich may cause that when you click in a position wich was valid by one of the previous moves (not the current position) it places a knight there.

Comment: it's funny that your code is very difficult to read.. your methods should describe behaviour @MaQy `tieneBoton` is like `hasButton` , `caballo` is `horse` in english doesn't mean behaviour , acciones is nothing.. is like actions(), your code i'll say in spanish es inmantenible e ilegible

Comment: sorry im quite new. Didnt know it was supposed to describe behaviour. I just named it to whatever comes in mind. THX

Comment: thx Evans any ideas in how can I correct this?

Comment: 7 questons asked. Not once have you accepted an answer. Now you start cross posting: http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/78793-problem-action-listening.html. I think I'll pass on your questions.

Comment: sorry man... How can I accept an answer. I cant level up the answer as usefull i need 15 rep :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Improvement would be for every subsequent if statment after

```
if (tienebotton(row+2, column+1)) {...}
```

Change to

`else if ...`

This would ensure that only one of those is fired.

Comment: fixt it with this for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
                bu = mesa[i][j].getActionListeners();
                for (int k = 0; k < bu.length; k++) {
                    bu = mesa[i][j].getActionListeners();
                    mesa[i][j].removeActionListener(bu[k]);
                }
            }
        } THX